# How can I integrate pagination to my search in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination

I've used codeigniter to make an easy search, no ajax or something, and I want to integrate the pagination class, I have read some examples and they use a library like this `$this->table->generate($results);` and I need in each result a button to edit that entry. I already did, but now with that way of showing the pagination I have a big problem, please, could anyone help me with this issue? I just need a clue or something to find in CI

I put here my model, controller and view, just in case

controller

```
public function searchdescription()
     {
     //$keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
     $keyword = $_POST['keyword']; 
     $this->load->model('searchdesc/searchdesc_model');
     $data['retorno'] = $this->searchdesc_model->querydb($keyword);
     $this->load->view('searchdesc/searchresults_view', $data);
}
```

model

```
function querydb($data,$num, $offset)
    {

    $queryresult = $this->db->query("select * from data where deleteflag=0  and title like     '%$data%' or text like '%$data%' LIMIT $num, $offset ");
    return $queryresult->result_array();
    }
```

view

```
foreach ($retorno as $val)
{
echo $val['id'];
echo $val['title'];
echo $val['text'];
...here are some forms autocreated in each row that i need to keep making it
}
```

Comment: Please read here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example (not using a model)

```
public function big()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/site/big/';
    $where = "bot = '2' OR bot = '0'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('visitors');
    $config['per_page'] = 15;
    //$config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     

    $where = "bot = '2' OR bot = '0'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->select('id, ip, date, page, host, agent, spammer, country, total, refer');
    $this->db->order_by("date", "DESC");
    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('visitors', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->table->set_heading('Id', 'IP', 'Date', 'Page', 'Host', 'Agent', 'Spam', 'Country', 'Total', 'Referer');

   $this->db->select_sum('total', 'trips');
   $query = $this->db->get('visitors');
   $data['trips'] = $query->result();

    $this->load->view('site_view', $data);      
}
```

In the view where I want the table:

```
<?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

to add buttons in the rows do something like this

```
foreach($records as $row){
$row->title = ucwords($row->title);

$this->table->add_row(
$row->date,
anchor("main/blog_view/$row->id", $row->title),
$row->status,    
anchor("main/delete/$row->id", $row->id, array('onClick' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')")),
anchor("main/fill_form/$row->id", $row->id)
);
}
$table = $this->table->generate();
echo $table;
```

Of course you will modify to fit your needs